# Data is not in human understandable text

Tags: c#, unicode, binary, ascii

i have a dictionary database (SQLite databse). the data in  one of the table is not understandable. the data is in this form

> !|"W"iX P"F"W#jX"Q#tX O I UX"Q _X _#t"QX _!y I#t!z#tX W!p W"FX!F!|
>   _!~#jX!p _!| _X T _!~!p IX J#t _ W#yX R IX"Q#t"i#jX!}"Q!p"i#jX"Q"F _ R _X#y#j

[Data in DataBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQLat.png)

i am working in C#. i applied different types of decoding (like ascii,utf8 etc). but nothing is working. any body have some idea.?

Comment: How do you retrieve said data (code)?

Comment: who put the data in? better ask the person about it

Comment: @Kilazur i am using sqliteconnection to retrieve the data and also use SQLite manager.

Comment: @Steve i don't know the person. i download this from internet and i don't remember the person.

Comment: Actually i am working on research project (my final year project) Based on NLP. i need dictionary  URDU to English or English to URDU. so i download the dictionary  app. the app is working fine but when i access the database from other source in this case .Net and SQLite manager the data is in not understandable text.

Comment: how are you reading the data from DB? I think you are doing it wrong

Comment: @Steve this is how i am accessing the DB.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dIIB_4y9T8qsKjRXlowJiXQhVgvCvV5e?usp=sharing

Comment: I am ready to bet that the string you posted is not a copy-paste, but what you think it looks like. My best guess is that the quotes and # and ! are in fact high bytes (beyond 0x7F) and the string is UTF-8. The Arabic script (used for Urdu) takes 2 bytes to encode as UTF-8, hence the " or ! or # showing up every two characters. So find a way to specify the encoding (I don't know how, as I don't know what library you use to access SQLite from C#)

Comment: @MihaiNita Thanks for reply but you lost the bit it is a copy past.